# Having trouble converting objective-c line to swift

Tags: objective-c, swift

I'm not sure exactly how to convert this line of objective-c to swift

```
  NSArray *pathComponents = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                           [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject],
                           @"MyAudioMemo.m4a",
                           nil];
```

Comment: What part has you confused? What was your attempt? What error message did you get with that attempt? To get good help on this site you have to show that you tried, at least a little.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very simply:

```
if let docsDir = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true).last as? String {
    let pathComponents = NSArray(objects: docsDir, "MyAudioMemo.m4a")
    ...
}
```

You can combine it all together into a single line, but then you have to implicitly unwrap the optional returned by the `last` computed property:

`var last: T? { get }`

Using the `if let` optional binding is safer, and a good habit to get into.

Comment: This code will generate a warning with Xcode 6 beta 7: `Constant 'docsDir' inferred to have type 'AnyObject', which may be unexpected`. Please edit your optional binding.